# Parameter for GET request changed by Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
params = {'token': 'JVFQ%2FFb5Ri2aKNtzTjOoErWvAaHRHsWHc8x%2FKGS%2FKAuoS4IRJI161l1rz2ab7rovBzGB86bGsh8pmDVaW8jj6AiJ2jT2rLIyt%2Bbpm80MCOE%3D'}
rsp = requests.get("http://xxxx/access", params=params)
print rsp.url
print params
```

when print `rsp.url`, I get

```
http://xxxx/access?token=JVFQ%252FFb5Ri2aKNtzTjOoErWvAaHRHsWHc8x%252FKGS%252FKAuoS4IRJI161l1rz2ab7rovBzGB86bGsh8pmDVaW8jj6AiJ2jT2rLIyt%252Bbpm80MCOE%253D    
JVFQ%2FF
JVFQ%252FF
```

The value of the `?token=` in the url is different from `params['token']`.
Why does it change?

Comment: Your parameter is already quoted, and requests is quoting it again, hence the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You passed in a *URL encoded value*, but `requests` encodes the value for you. As a result, the value is encoded twice; the `%` character is encoded to `%25`.

Don't pass in a URL-encoded value. Decode it manually if you must:

```
from urllib import unquote

params['token'] = unquote(params['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

URL's use a special type of syntax. The % character is a reserved character in URLs. It is used as an escape character to allow you to type other characters (such as space, @, and % itself).

Requests automatically encodes URLs to proper syntax when necessary. The % key had to be econded to "%25". In other words, the URL parameters never changed. They are the same. The URL was just encoded to proper syntax. Everywhere you put "%" it was encoded to the proper form of "%25"

You can check out URL Syntax info here if you want: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax

And you can encode/decode URLs here. Try encoding "%" or try decoding "%25" to see what you get:
http://www.url-encode-decode.com/